# Calculate the marginal pdf given joint pdf

Tags: probability

Given a joint pdf:
$$
f_{X,Y}(x,y)=\begin{cases}{3\over 8}x&0\le x\le 2\wedge 0\le y\le x\\0&o.w\end{cases}
$$
Find the marginal pdf of Y - $f_Y(y)$
This is my solution:
First I changed the limits of $x$ in order to perform the integral properly
$$
\begin{matrix}
0\le x\le 2\\
0\le y\le x
\end{matrix}
\Longrightarrow
\begin{matrix}
y\le x\le 2\\0\le y\le 2
\end{matrix}
$$
and then
$$
f_Y(y)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{X,Y}(x,y) dx =\int_y^2{3\over 8}xdx=\frac{3}{8}\frac{x^2}{2}\big\vert _y^2 =\frac{3}{8}\Big(\frac{2^2}2-\frac{y^2}{2}\Big)=\frac{3}{16}\big(4-y^2 \big)
$$

Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: Great, thank you.

Comment: But it is only correct for $0 \le y \le 2$. For any other value $f_Y(y) = 0$...

Comment: Yes of course, I should've mentioned it.